# Evidently, we are porn

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I tried to log in today from a private club, and got back the following error, which I have never before seen,

[image: eek, porn!]

I think the error page identified the censoring service as being provided by Sonicwall. If anybody has friends there, perhaps ask them to expedite having this fixed. Also let them know how to spell "inappropriate," as they seem to have failed to do it correctly on their own.

Comment: Is this England?? :)

Comment: I blame [Lena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna). :-p

Comment: Well, I'm sorry that your private club chose to use SonicWall products. You might like to suggest that they switch to higher-quality hardware in the future.

Comment: I think we all agree that Spikey (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spikey.html) is very sexy :-)

Comment: might be due to this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66538/how-do-i-draw-a-pair-of-buttocks

Answer (score 14):

You can submit a request for review yourself at the following URL: http://cfssupport.sonicwall.com/Support/servlet/CFSSupportServlet/viewRating

[image: the form itself]

According to the page shown upon submission of this form, it can take 3-5 days for a review to take place. Let's hope they get it right this time.

Also, stop posting dirty pictures. Even if they *are* fully rendered.

---

The reply I received:

> You submitted the following rating request to SonicWALL CFS Support:
>   Rate mathematica.stackexchange.com as "27.Information Tech/Computers" at 2014-01-24 21:25:00.707
>
> The request has been reviewed and rated as:
>   "27.Information Tech/Computers" at 2014-01-25 13:50:20.837
>
> You should see this rating change reflected within 1 to 3 business days.
>
> Thank you for your request,
>           SonicWALL CFS Support

Comment: To be clear, I submitted a request that they reconsider before I posted here. And nothing will ever stop me from using Mathematica to render my sweet, sweet algorithmic porn.

Comment: See edit, @michael

Comment: I got that notice as well. What in our discussion might have triggered their bot to have misclassified this site in the first place? My best guess is all the discussion of Head[] and Sin[].

Comment: Also `Root`, `Insert`, `Take`, `Position`, and `NeedlemanWunschSimilarity`.

Comment: I just spit-laughed my tea over my laptop at your' Cult/Occult' rating suggestion submission...

Comment: @rasher Well look who's running the place. <|:^)

Comment: @rasher On this site, there's a wizard, a Celtic goddess and a crazy Byzantine general performing ritualistic toad and cat sacrifices (actually, the toad killings might be more for pleasure than a ritual...). Cult/Occult seems more than appropriate =)

Comment: @wxffles Don't forget `ForwardBackward`, `Reverse`, `FinishDynamic`, `HumpDownHump` (and many more gems in inner contexts) :D